# display cursor next to an contenteditable="false" element

Tags: html, contenteditable

when there is an [contenteditable=false] element inside an editable div, it seems impossible for users to add more content after it, and the type cursor is not showing next to it.

is there a way to fix this problem?

```css
[contenteditable="false"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
<p>text</p>
<div contenteditable="false">
an uneditable block element, try adding text after me...
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily because their is no region for the cursor to be inserted.

Can't you just add a spacer?

```css
[contenteditable="false"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>text</p>
  <div contenteditable="false">
    an uneditable block element, try adding text after me...
  </div>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: but the user can delete the space, which makes it back to the awkward scenario again

Comment: @Littlee but doing it in this manner they could also delete the whole ce="flase" div. Does it need to be nested inside? can you just create three seperate regions?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can add `<hr>` to the end of the container (checking if it was erased by the interaction).
I used it because this is a single tag and the user cannot enter text inside (as if we were using an empty `<span>`).

```css
hr {
  display: inline;
}
```

```js
checkForCaretHelper() {
  if (this.container.getElementsByTagName('hr').length === 0) {
    this.container.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
  }
}
```